# Swing custom painting: should `Graphic` object be disposed?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, custom-painting

When overriding `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` in any `JComponent` to perform custom painting of that `JComponent`, should the `Graphic` object `g` be disposed at the end of the painting  (and why)?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);       
    g.drawString("To dispose or not to dispose ? ",10,20);
    //dispose or avoid ?
    g.dispose();  
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling dispose() on Graphics object cause JPanel to not render any components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911743/why-does-calling-dispose-on-graphics-object-cause-jpanel-to-not-render-any-com)

Comment: @isaace "You only need to dispose of Graphics when you actually create it"  in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13911783/3992939) does answer my question. It does not explain why you should refrain from disposing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not dispose of the `Graphics` object unless your code creates the `Graphics` object.

The `paint()` method of `JComponent` will create a `Graphics` object and pass it to the three painting methods of each component.
See: [A Closer Look at the Painting Mechanisn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html).

The `paint()` method will then `dispose()` of this temporary `Graphics` object when painting of the component is finished. Check out the code at: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/JComponent.java

If you manually create a Graphics object then you should dispose it:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();

// do custom painting

g2d.dispose();
```

Typically it is a good idea to create a copy of the passed Graphics object if you intend to alter the painting by adding an AffineTransform, for example, to the Graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you didn't create the resource, it's not your job to dispose of it. As that Graphics is being passed to you, I wouldn't worry about disposing of it.

Answer (score 1):

No do not dispose the Graphics object in paintComponent. This will prevent other Components from drawing.

The right way to use Graphics.dispose is when you are drawing to an image buffer, like

```
BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(...,...);
Graphics g = im.getGraphics();
JPanel.paint(g); // for example
g.drawLine(...); // another example
g.dispose();
```