# Why can't I draw something on the screen?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

class Screen extends Canvas {

    public static JFrame window(int width,int height,String title) {
        System.out.println("window()");
        JFrame window = new JFrame(title);
        
        window.setSize(width,height);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setVisible(true);
        
        return window;
    }
    
    public static Canvas canvas(int width,int height) {
        System.out.println("canvas()");
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setSize(width, height);
        
        return canvas;
    }
    
    public static Graphics createGraphics(Canvas window,BufferStrategy strategy) {
        System.out.println("createGraphics()");
         
         Graphics graphics = strategy.getDrawGraphics();
         return graphics;
    }
    
    public static BufferStrategy createStrategy(JFrame window) {
        window.createBufferStrategy(2);
        BufferStrategy strategy = window.getBufferStrategy();
        
        return strategy;
    }
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame window = window(800,600,"Application");
        Canvas canvas = canvas(800,600);
        BufferStrategy strategy = createStrategy(window);
        
        window.add(canvas);
        
        while(true) {
            Graphics g = createGraphics(canvas,strategy);
            
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
            
            
            
            g.dispose();
            strategy.show();
        }
        
        
    }

}
```

I was expecting to draw something on the screen but it didn't work. I don't know if Graphics and Bufferstrategy have to be used in the same place. Check my code, logically I think there is no problem.My goal is to draw a square on the screen

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68864382/swing-custom-painting-should-graphic-object-be-disposed

Answer (score 0):

```
`import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Screen extends Canvas {
    
    
    public static JFrame window(int width,int height,String title) {
        System.out.println("window()");
        JFrame window = new JFrame(title);
        
        window.setSize(width,height);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setVisible(true);
        
        return window;
    }
    
    public static Canvas canvas(int width,int height) {
        System.out.println("canvas()");
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setSize(width, height);
        
        return canvas;
    }
    
    public static void player(Graphics graphics,int player_x,int player_y) {
        
        graphics.fillRect(player_x,player_y , 50, 50);
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame window = window(800,600,"Application");
        Canvas canvas = canvas(800,600);
        
        int p_x = 20;
        int p_y = 20;
        
        window.add(canvas);
        
        while(true) {
            Graphics graphics = canvas.getGraphics();
            
            // Worked
            // graphics.drawanything()
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    
}`
```

This worked.

Comment: if you do not need buffering, I would suggest [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: My fault, I wasted your time. Please accept my apology.But my comment above will be useful for me in the future, thanks for that.