# How to programmatically remove background of an image in java?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

Using bufferedImage or something is there a quick way to do this?

At present my approach:

All the images are centered on a white background. So the top left pixel is always white.

- Start at the top left pixel, make it transparent.
- From this pixel, see if any of the bordering pixels are white, if there are, make it transparent. For each of the bordering pixels that were white, check that pixels bordering pixels, and repeat for all connected pixels.

This seems ok to me. But I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Better? In terms of performance? In terms of logic? In terms of reusing libraries that can do that for you? I fear your question is unfortunately too broad to be answered as it is.

Comment: Does anything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672697/java-filling-a-bufferedimage-with-transparent-pixels) help? The bit about being backed with int[] and directly manipulating looked promising...

Comment: Have a look at the [Starbucks logo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starbucks#/media/File:Starbucks_Corporation_Logo_2011.svg) - your floodfill algorithm will transaparentize the mermaid's body, hair, and parts of the leg scale things (try not to think about what the position of those elements implies the mermaid's full pose is. Cripes what a logo). Some logos are fundamentally impossible to re-transparentize. Now look to your top left and check out the stack overflow logo. The image thing (the basket with the orange lines) goes fine. But the inside of the 'a', 'e', and the two 'o's will fail.

Comment: Re-transparantizing simply doesn' work the way you want it to. It's not the algorithm to use. The more appropriate algorithm is _generally_ to find every white pixel and replace it with transparent, no flood fill: Just find __every pixel__. However, this still fails for half-transparent. Whatever process messed up the image (replaced transparency with white) will have replaced a solid blue pixel (`#0000FF`) that is half transparent with a half-blue, half-white pixel (`#FF8888`). Replacing every full-white pixel with transparency will result in an extremely ugly edge.

Comment: The answer to the question: "I have some logos that were rendered on white background; how do I restore their transparency" therefore is either [A] tough, you __cannot do this, information has been destroyed__, or [B] you need some serious AI, which likely does the job by essentially finding that logo in its training data, i.e. it's doing what the __actual answer is__: There is nothing for it, but to find transparent takes on it. Or do it by hand and use artistic judgement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

AFAIK, no.  (In fact, I *suspect* that it is provable that there is no alternative to your *general* approach.)

However, your *"repeat for all connected pixels"* doesn't specify how you do that.  The obvious alternatives are:

- Recursive depth first - this is probably a bad idea, because there is a risk that you will overflow your call stack.
- Breadth first using a queue of pixel positions for white pixels that are yet to be processed.  This will process the pixels in a wave, and the maximum queue length will be the maximum wave "width".

There may be other strategies.

This problem is similar to flood filling, and flood-fill algorithms can be adapted to do this.  Look at [Best way to fill shapes in Java (no recursion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836646) for some examples.

Comment: Thank you for the link that seems useful. I was basically implementing my own flood algorithm, but since many graphic editors have their own tool for removing backgrounds I figured there must be some general purpose solution readily available besides me doing it myself.

Comment: *"... since many graphic editors have their own tool for removing backgrounds I figured there must be some general purpose solution readily available besides me doing it myself."* - That doesn't follow at all.  But even if it did, what would that solution be?  Note that request for library or tool recommendations are off-topic!!